# SVG pixel ratio is 1:2 from code to rendering

Tags: javascript, html, svg

When rendering my SVG the x, y, width and height are doubling in pixels. What is causing this?

**EDIT:**

Monitor is 3840 X 2160 with 200% scale in windows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #svg {
            border-style: solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <svg id="svg" width="300px" height="200px">
        <image x="20" y="20" width="100px" height="100px" xlink:href="test_image.png"></image>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have zoomed in your browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows scaling was set to 200% with a 3840 X 2160 monitor causing the SVG pixel ratio to be 1:2 from code to rendering.

Answer (score -1):

I would have added a comment, but dont have enough reputation.

Your code worked as expected for me, the ratio's were correct. Could it be related to the image or the browser you are viewing it in?

You could also try changing just the SVG or the Image attributes to narrow down the issue.

You can play with the SVG image properties from here: [www3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElement)